# Handling HTTP 404 using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, http-status-code-404

Clicking on a hyperlink is throwing me the below error.

Please suggest me how to handle this is below exception.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to check for the response code of the URL:

```
public static boolean getResponseCode(String chkurl) {
        boolean validResponse = false;
            try {   
                //Get response code of URL
                HttpResponse urlresp = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(chkurl));
                int resp_Code = urlresp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                System.out.println("Response Code Is : "+resp_Code +" for "+chkurl);
                if ((resp_Code == 404) || (resp_Code == 505)) {
                    validResponse = false;
                    } else {
                    validResponse = true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                return validResponse;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way to check do HTTP status code directly using Webdriver. You can use a HTTP client directly, but if the problem is a 500 code, or a 403, it can become unwieldy. We cover a more powerful technique using Mob Browser Proxy with WedDriver in our book:

http://selenium-webdriver-in-practice.github.io